# jQuery/Javascript - Edit and delete appended elements by different click times

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, long-click

I want to make a list in which the user can add elements by clicking a button, change their colour by one click on the element and delete them with a long click on the element.

My code works fine for adding divs and changing their color:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
    var toAdd = $('input[name=shop-item]').val();
    if (toAdd == ''){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $('#list').append('<div class="item item-red">' + toAdd + '</div>');
    });

$(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('item-red');
    $(this).toggleClass('item-green');
});
```

But then I would like to be able to delete a single div with a long click. I found some examples like the following:

```
var timeoutId = 0;
$(document).on('mousedown', '.item', function(){
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){ $(this).remove() }, 500);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

However, it doesn't work with '`this`'. But if I use '`.item`' instead, obviously all the appended items are deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `setTimeout` function, you are in a different scope. `this` has a different meaning. You could cache it instead:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.item', function(){
    var $this= $(this);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){ $this.remove() }, 500);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the mousedown event timestamp
every event has timestamp in its prototype

`var mouseDownTimestamp = 0
    $(document).on('mousedown',function(event){
        mouseDownTimestamp = event.timeStamp;}
    );
    $(document).on('mouseup',function(event){
        //if the mouse up is after 499ms
        if(mouseDownTimestamp < event.timeStamp - 499){
            //or $(event.target).remove();
            //or $(event.target).closest('.class of the holder').remove();
            $(selector).remove();
        }
    });`